# Storing type in each table or give item a type

Tags: mysql, database-design

I need to design schema for a project that involves two things.
1. providing services ( realted to vechicles)
2. Also sells insurance and spare parts


Below is the schema that I have designed so far.

```
Items which can be services or spare parts or other things

Services
--------------------
service_id
service_request_number
vehicle_id
user_id
status_id

Spare Parts
-------------------
spare_part_id
name
description
spare_part_detail_id
hsn_code
cat_id
```

I treated service too as a item that can be sold like others.

Below is the user's Cart.

```
Cart
--------------------
cart_id
user_id

CartItems
------------------
cart_item_id
cart_id
cart_item_id
quantity
// should I also place item type here?

Items_type
------------------
item_type_id
item_type // service, insurance, spare parts
```

So against each cart item an order would be placed. 

Order processing would be different according to item_type.

So I want to know, 
 *Should I insert `item_type_id` in `Orders` and `Cart Items` tables, Or should I just store `item_type_id` in each table of the item?*
Like: in `services put a item_type_id`s.so all in other.

But Further I have two other tables.

```
UsedCouponDetails
--------------------------------
id
coupon_id
item_id
item_type //should I store it here too
```

As it is clear that If just store `item_id` in `UsedCoupons` , querying would take time just know type of the item. 

Also there can two entries with same item_id.
That would cause ambiguity
This is what I have tried for now, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60427559/how-to-build-a-schema-with-multiple-type-of-items-services-parts-and-insuranc).
Can someone someone suggest a better approach?

Comment: This looks familiar; did you post it somewhere else?  If so, add the link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60427559/how-to-build-a-schema-with-multiple-type-of-items-services-parts-and-insuranc